# Fading TextMeshPro Alpha is instantly fading

Tags: unity-game-engine, fade

I tried using LeanTween and now wrote my own coroutine, neither of them work. The goal is, to have the text of a TextMeshPro element fade in / out over a duration, which should be simple enough but apparently isn't. Here is the coroutine:

```
private IEnumerator FadeText(float target, float duration) {
        Color color = text.color;
        float timer = 0f;
        float alpha = color.a;
        while(timer < duration) {
            timer += Time.deltaTime;
            print($"{timer / duration}% is: {Mathf.Lerp(alpha, target, timer / duration)}");
            color.a = Mathf.Lerp(alpha, target, timer / duration);
            text.color = color;

            yield return new WaitForEndOfFrame();
        }
    }
```

The Debug.Log shows the correct values (going from 0 to 255 and vice versa over the desired duration) but the text simply pops in. Here is how the code above looks like (again: using LeanTween had the same result):
[Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/m3Dak.gif)

The text "upgrades" is supposed to fade in over 5 seconds, and fade out over 0.4 seconds.

Am i missing something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

look into the [API -> `Color`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Color.html)

> Each color component is a **floating point value with a range from 0 to 1.**

The raw color type would be [`Color32`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Color32.html) where rather

> Each color component is a byte value with a range from 0 to 255.

So either

- use a `Color32` (there are implicit conversions between `Color` and `Color32` so you can basically use them exchangeable, see [`Color32.Color`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Color32-operator_Color32.html) and [`Color32.Color32`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Color32-operator_Color.html))
- or simply change the input value to be a `float` between `0` and `1`.

Answer (score 0):

As it turns out, Color internally works with values between 0 and 1, not between 0 and 255 which i always thought. Using the code above with 0 and 1 works as intended. Same goes for the LeanTween version.

Answer (score 0):

```
private float timeElapsed;
private float valueToLerp;
private float delayTime = 5f; 
    Update()
    {
        if ( FadeOut)
        {
            valueToLerp = Mathf.Lerp(1, 0, timeElapsed / delayTime);
            timeElapsed += Time.deltaTime;
            textMesh.color = new Color(textMesh.color.r, textMesh.color.g,textMesh.color.b, valueToLerp);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Code-only answers are generally considered lower quality or desirability than answers that include an explanation of how they were constructed or what concepts are needed that the questioner seemed to lack.